# Using an inline item renderer to edit my DATAGRID

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Good evening. I have a problem in my datagrid itemeditor
This is my data grid component

```
<mx:DataGrid id="lessonPlanDataGrid" x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{studentLessonPlanArray}" height="271" width="270" editable="true">

<mx:columns>    
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Activity Name" dataField="activityname" textAlign="center"/>     
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Duration(minutes)" dataField="time" textAlign="center" editable="true">
<mx:itemEditor>
<fx:Component>              
<mx:NumericStepper stepSize="1" maximum="20"/>

</fx:Component>

</mx:itemEditor>    

</mx:DataGridColumn>

</mx:columns>

</mx:DataGrid>
```

Whenever i change the value it gives me this error

```
Error #1069: Property text not found on Forms.LessonPlanInnerClass0 and there is no default value.
    at mx.controls::DataGrid/itemEditorItemEditEndHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\DataGrid.as:5296]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
```

the array StudentLessonPlanArray is a bindable array

Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

Try setting editorDataField to 'value' on the DataGridColumn with the custom itemEditor.  This property tells Flex which property contains the value that should be applied when editing ends.  The default item editor is TextInput, and so the default value for editorDataField is 'text'